# IntelliJ Not Recognizing Glassfish Server

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish

I am able to run Glasssfish server perfectly on port 8080. But IntelliJ is not recognizing it or the option to select it and configure it in IntelliJ is not there when selecting

```
run -> edit configurations
```

you can see this in the image attached.

what gives?
thanks,
CM

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer is you need the Ultimate edition of IntelliJ. 
CM